# beast. Возвращение jpeg в теле ответа на get запрос

Tags: c++, boost

HTTP клиент на boost::beast, get запрос, получаю ответ, в теле ответа jpeg картинка. Как ее сохранить в файл?

beast::multi_buffer::const_buffers_type data = body.data();

В случае, если возвращается JSON, просто преобразовываю data в строку:

string json = beast::buffers_to_string(data);

КОГДА ПРИШЛА КАРТИНКА Я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
ofstream outFile("foto_screen.jpg", ios::binary | ios::out);
    
    for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++)
    {
        string ss = beast::buffers_to_string(*it);
        outFile.write(ss.c_str(), sizeof ss.c_str());
    }
    outFile.close();
```

файл сохраняется, но картинка не открывается.

Comment: Открыть файл на бинарную запись (`wb`), засунуть массив байт (т.е. картинку) в него. Это алгоритм для любого языка :)

Comment: ¿Что по-вашему возвращает `sizeof ss.c_str()`? ¿И зачем там вообще создается промежуточный объект `string`?

Comment: Это конечно же очевидно. Но вопрос был поставлен относительно поступивших данных, а не о том как эти данные записать. Вы ,наверное, такими комментариями увеличиваете баллы репутации? Я для чего вопрос задал? Что бы специалист по beast или человек разобравшийся в вопросе помог. А ваши комментарии... Лучше не помогайте таким способом никогда и ни кому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что data имеет тип beast::multi_buffer::const_buffers_type. Это контейнер для других буферов (их может быть несколько). Итератор возвращает указатель на очередной буфер типа boost::asio::const_buffer.
Тип boost::asio::const_buffer - имеет функцию data() возвращающую значение типа const void* и функцию - size() - размер data  в байтах.
Для записи массива байт потребовалось привести const void* к типу const char* и передать в функцию write.

```
ofstream outFile("foto_screen.jpg", ios::binary | ios::out);

for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++)
{
    boost::asio::const_buffer d = *it;        
    const void* a = d.data();
    const char* f = (char*) a;

    outFile.write(f, d.size());

}
 
outFile.close();
```